# How to access Classloaders/App Linearalloc classinformation size?

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk, classloader, dalvik

***INFO: Its not the LinearAlloc problem which should be solved here!***

Hi,

my problem is the analysis of a LinearAlloc exceeded capacity error(1). While i already have a solution for the error, i still need a way to analyse the used size of the running application.
I am using Android 4.0.3 (updating is not an option), which means that the capacity is 8mb.

The error occurs at runtime, because the application/library is loaded dynamicaly(2).
In LinearAlloc.cpp (3) on Line 306 would be my Solution:

`LOGVV("--- old=%d size=%d new=%d", startOffset, size, nextOffset);`

***How to enable the VeryVerbose Loglevel?***

Or

***Is there another way to access the size of the used memory of bootclasspath classloader header(see (3))?***

***Maybe from NDK-Api?***

If I am informed correctly it is the memory for classinformation.
The specific memory for that usage is what I am looking for.

***How much of the capacity is used and how can it be accessed at runtime?***

It is not necessary to access it in code I just need the value.
If it is calculable from `dumpsys meminfo` or `DDMS` would it also solve the problem.

Solutions which don't need root are preffered!

(1)[LinearAlloc exceeded capacity](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22586)

(2) Not allowed to post 3 links: google: Custom Classloading Android

(3)[LinearAlloc.cpp](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/dalvik/vm/LinearAlloc.cpp)

Edit: Added NDK-API as possible solution.

P.S. It is my first question/post any suggestions for improvment are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is not a SDK/NDK API for Dalvik LinearAlloc Size. But you can calculate this size by accessing Linux Interface /proc//smap for the detail information.

Smap:

```
/dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc
```

In Dalvik code, this memory max map size is **16M**. And this memory is alloced by mmap, so the basic block is 4K. So if you want to calcuate this memory usage is using `RSS` @ Smap.